# Weekly Calendar calculation in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

Trying to develop an application similar to stock calendar. I am trying weekly view on my app.

I have the current weeks date showing up properly.

Now I am trying to get the previous and Next week calculation done. I tried the following for previous Calculation:

```
if(calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == calender.getActualMinimum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)) 
{   
 calender.set((calender.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1), calender.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR), 1);
} 
else 
{
    calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-1);
}

week = calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);

Log.e("Week","+ week"+ week);
Log.e("Year","+ Year"+ year);
```

Here the log for weeks are coming up properly until week 1 (Jan 1st) when it comes to previous year that is where I am getting an issue. The log is showing Week as 18 and year as 2017. I am not sure why?

For next week: When it comes to end of December it starts from Week 6 and not week 1. Strange things are happening?

Is there a better way to get previous week or Next week?

Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue: Thought this might be useful for people who are struggling to get the previous and next weeks numbers.

**FOR GETTING PREVIOUS WEEK:**

```
if(calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == 2) 
{   
    calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1);
    calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
} 
else 
{
  calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1);
}

week = calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
fetchData(week, year);
break;
```

**FOR GETTING NEXT WEEK:**

```
if(calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == calender.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)) 
{   
 calender.set(Calendar.YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
 calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
} 
else 
{
 calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + 1);
}

week = calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
fetchData(week, year);
```

**PS:** fetchData is method if you give week and year to it it will give the dates for that week.

Hope it is useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question has nothing to do with Android. Calendar is an Java API. Please edit your question tags.

Your mistake is in this part of the code:

```
 calender.set((calender.get(Calendar.YEAR)-1), calender.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR), 1);
```

No matter if you are in the first week of the year, if you want to get the previous one, just call the following method:

```
calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1);
```

Apart from setting your current week to the previous one, the method `set()` also calculates the year and day after your modifications.

This code:

```
calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
System.out.println("Day: " +  calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println("Week: " +  calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println("Year: " +  calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));

calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1);
System.out.println("Day: " +  calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println("Week: " +  calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
System.out.println("Year: " +  calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Produces this output:

```
Day: 1
Week: 1
Year: 2015
Day: 359
Week: 52
Year: 2014
```

Comment: I tried like what ever you told me already. I get week 1 2014 and Week 52 as 2015 - Please take a look at the problem here LOG FILE:  http://pastebin.com/aQW2XKJs

Comment: There's something you're doing wrong. This code i posted works just fine. Change your entire `if` clause posted above with this: `calender.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1);`. This is straight up native java code. If it works for me, it works for you.

Comment: If I use the code like above setting Day_OF_YEAR as 1 and try it it is working but I don't set Day of Year onCreate I am getting results like the log. Are you getting the results even though you don't send the day of year?

Comment: Can you please check and tell me..because I am not getting the results.

Comment: You don't need to set the day of the year. I just used it for the sake of the example. To get the previous and next week of a certain date all you have to do is use 'calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) +/- 1'. By the way, you haven't read the Calendar API docs did you ? You should really search more before posting simple questions like this. There is plenty of methods available on the internet showing what you want and also how to discover which days of year belong to that week.

Comment: If I don't set the week_of_year I end up getting values similar to Log that is pasted before. hence I set the week of year...  I did read the docs and hence I came out a solution like my question. this doesn't seem to be simple for me (like +1 and -1) I am not getting the results for previous year and next year (weekly). :(

Comment: 1) You're not trying hard enough. 2) You're not making any sense anymore. Your question was `Is there a better way to get previous week or Next week?` and i've answered it properly. 3) `I am not getting the results for previous year and next year` This is a different question from the previous one.